# Compare string of array to another string of array

Tags: powershell, oop, wildcard

I'm trying to compare a string within an array to another string within another array

I feel like the logic is right but for some reason couldn't get the expected output

The array **$groupslist** has  values of "cn-sg-robot-platform","cn-sg-capture-platform","cn-sg-easy-platform","cn-sg-content-platform"

The array **$comparestrings** has values "sg-robot-platform" , "sg-easy-platform"

I want to print a message if $comparestring value is present in $groupslist ( if sg-robot-platform is present in cn-sg-robot-platform it should print a message )

The code which I tried isn't performing pattern search :(

```
$AdGroup = "cn-sg-robot-platform","cn-sg-capture-platform","cn-sg-easy-platform","cn-sg-content-platform"
$comparestrings = "sg-robot-platform" , "sg-easy-platform"

foreach ($item in $AdGroup) {
    $matchFound = $false
    foreach ($dev in $comparestrings) {
        if ($dev -like "*$item*") {
            $matchFound = $true
            echo "Match found"
            break
        }
    }
    if (-not $matchFound) {
        Write-Host "No match found for $item"
    }
}
```

**I want to print the match found when sg-robot-platform matches with cn-sg-robot-platform pattern **

Comment: Have you tried `if ($item -like "*$dev*") {` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you intend to do here, but if you want to output where a match can be found, here's two possible solutions for you:

1. loop over the $comparestrings array and test each value if there is a match

```powershell
$groupslist     = "cn-sg-robot-platform","cn-sg-capture-platform","cn-sg-easy-platform","cn-sg-content-platform"
$comparestrings = "sg-robot-platform" , "sg-easy-platform"

foreach ($item in $comparestrings) {
    if ($groupslist -like "*$item*") {
        "Match found for $item"
    }
}
```

2. use `Where-Object` and loop over the results

```powershell
$groupslist     = "cn-sg-robot-platform","cn-sg-capture-platform","cn-sg-easy-platform","cn-sg-content-platform"
$comparestrings = "sg-robot-platform" , "sg-easy-platform"

$comparestrings | Where-Object { $groupslist -like "*$item*" } | ForEach-Object { "Match found for $_" }
# or use regex -match
# $comparestrings | Where-Object { $groupslist -match $item } | ForEach-Object { "Match found for $_" }
```

Both will output

```
Match found for sg-robot-platform
Match found for sg-easy-platform
```